# Tag bits required in TLB

Tags: virtual-machine, virtual-memory, tlb

There is a 32-bit virtual address space in the machine and a 30-bit physical address space, with a virtual memory page size of 8 KBytes. The translation look-aside buffer (TLB) is organized to have 64 total entries and is 4-way set associative. And the L1 data cache organization parameters are 16 KByte, 2-way set associative, 64-byte block/line size. The L1 cache is also physically tagged.

- Can someone explain how I could calculate the tag bits in the TLB?
- And how many tag bits will be required for each L1 cache block?